# Ext4 volume as File on NTFS volume

Tags: mount, ntfs, ext4, iso

I was running out of space on my ext3 root volume , so I created a Ext4 Volume as a file and saved it on a NTFS partition. Then made this ext4 vol as a permanent mount.

Purpose was to have all the linux file permissions but NTFS doesn't allow this.

Is it the right approach ? 
I see a lot of IO happens on the NTFS partition when i access the mounted (ext4) vol, Is it ok ?

Comment: Was there a special reason for not creating a "real" ext4-partition on this drive?

Comment: My NTFS partition is not shrinking.  I couldn't find the reason for it. I have tried using gparted, somw windows partitioning software.

Comment: You may want to try shrinking again (**make a backup first!**). You may also find some useful information here: [Gparted/NTFS](http://askubuntu.com/q/1813), [unmovable files](http://askubuntu.com/q/25221), [external USB](http://askubuntu.com/q/30220), [GParted](http://askubuntu.com/q/47409), [Unmout partitions incl. Swap](http://askubuntu.com/q/51272)

Comment: The NTFS driver is *extremely* slow with large files. You should resize the partitions instead.

Answer (score 3):

On my opinion this is the wrong approach, your Kernel needs to run two file system drivers (ext4 and ntfs3g) to store and read data and write access with ntfs3g is still somewhat not trusted. I used NTFS on my Ubuntu machine for a long time now and already once had issues with data loss, so please use this with much care for sensible data. Also access to this partition should be somewhat slow.

The "correct" way is to shrink the size of the NTFS-partition and create a real ext4-partition in the generated free space.